# Symfony2 - How to setup a session from a cookie from another project

Tags: php, session, symfony, cookies, authentication

I have two projects 1 amd 2.

The project 1 is in pure php and the project 2 is in symfony.

I have a login function in the project 1 which will generate a cookie.

Then, I would like to use this cookie with the project 2 so that I do not have to login again.

The user database is the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the projects on the same domain? If not, browsers will not send the cookie as it 'not belongs' to two domains.

Comment: @StijnvanGrinsven, yes, the projects are on the same domain, on the same server. In fact, in the server settings, I am accessing the project 2 from the project 1, so it has access to the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out the name and dataformat/content of the cookie. In your project2, access the details via $_COOKIE[name-of-cookie] and verify its content. It can be anything But probable a hashed version of a / some database values. If all is correct, your project 2 can no say it is logged in ( probably a userid is also within the cookie ). Since you share the database between projects,you can load your user entity from the database now and know the specific details of the logged in user like name, etc